# Approximate AR(p) with a product of AR(1) and AR(2)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autoregressive, decomposition

Literature suggests that any AR(p) ARIMA model can approximated as a combination of AR(1) and AR(2) processes.

For example, one book suggests that an AR(3) model with the following coefficients:

- Lag1 = -0.58
- Lag2 = -0.63
- Lag3 = -0.21

Can be factored approximately into the following AR(2) and AR(1) components:

```
(1 + 0.58B + 0.63B^2 + 0.21B^3) ~ (1 + 0.2B + 0.5B^2)(1 + 0.4B)
```

I want to use this decomposition to estimate the AR(2) component for another forecast. Is there software or math that dictates how to do this decomposition for a given AR(3) or AR(p) model?

I ultimately want to use this to estimate whether or not there is a stochastic cycle in my process, which I can check for an AR(2) process with the following formula:

```
Lag1^2 + 4*Lag2 < 0
```

but don't know how to check for an AR(3) process. I thought the best way would be to decompose it into an AR(2) and AR(1), then check for the existence of a stochastic cycle in the AR(2) term. If there's a simpler way check for stochastic cycles in AR(3) models, that would also be appreciated!

Comment: This is not linear combination, this is a product.

Comment: Whoops, good catch, that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following two processes (using your notation):

$$ 1 + a_1B + a_2 B^2 $$

$$ 1 + a_3B $$

Multiply them:

$$ (1 + a_1B + a_2 B^2)(1 + a_3B) = 1 + (a_1 + a_3)B + (a_1 a_3 + a_2)B^2 + a_2 a_3 B^3 $$

The latter is an AR(3). If you start from a given AR(3):

$$ 1 + c_1B + c_2B^2 + c_3B^3 $$

Then you have a 3x3 equation system:

$$ c_1 = a_1 + a_3 $$ 
$$ c_2 = a_1 a_3 + a_2 $$
$$ c_3 = a_2 a_3 $$

The solution(s) involve quadratic terms, which depends on the values of $c_i$. Albeit not every AR(3) is in principle decomposable as **the multiplication** of an AR(1) and AR(2) process (in the sense that its coefficients are real numbers), you can solve the system in order to find the conditions in terms of $c_i$ that make such decomposition possible.

Ultimately, this is nothing else than [polynomial decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_decomposition), so you can extend the method to any AR(p).

Comment: +1, but I think calling $1 + a_1B + a_2 B^2$ and the other ones "processes" is imprecise. These are polynomials in lag operators.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Also was curious about if there's a better way to check for stochastic cycles on higher order arima terms (as opposed to decomposition into smaller terms) but I think that might be for another question. Accepted answer!